# Equation of plane containing a point and a line

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

> Find the equation of the plane containing the point $A(0,1,-1)$ and the line
>   $(d) : \begin{cases} 2x - y + z + 1 = 0 \\ x + y + 1 = 0 \end{cases}$

Where should I start? I was thinking about writing the normal vectors for the line and make their cross product or something like that, but I don't really understand what's going on here. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ satisfies an equation of the type

\begin{equation}
ax+by+cz+d=0.  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
You can reduce this problem to that of finding a plane defined by 3 points. So just find 2 points on the line $ d $, using the given equations. For $x=0$ and $x=1$ you get, respectively, the points $B\left(
0,-1,-2\right) $ and $C\left( 1,-2,-5\right) $. To find 3 out of all the constants $a,b,c,d$ you need to substitute the coordinates of $A,B,C$ into $(1)$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
b-c+d=0 \\ 
-b-2c+d=0 \\ 
a-2b-5c+d=0
\end{array}
\right.  &\Leftrightarrow &\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
b-c+d=0 \\ 
-3c+2d=0 \\ 
a-2b-5c+d=0
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow \ldots 
&\Leftrightarrow &\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
b+\frac{1}{2}c=0 \\ 
d=\frac{3}{2}c \\ 
a-2b-5c+\frac{3}{2}c=0,
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{eqnarray*}
whose solution in terms of $c$ is $d=\frac{3}{2}c,a=\frac{5}{2}c,b=-\frac{1}{2}c$. So

$$
\frac{5}{2}cx-\frac{1}{2}cy+cz+\frac{3}{2}c=0
$$
and, finally, dividing by $c/2$ we obtain the equation of the plane
$$
5x-y+2z+3=0.\tag{2}
$$

Plot of plane $(2)$, line $d$ and points $A, B, C$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The pencil of planes through  the line with equations $2x-y+z+1=0,\;x+y+1=0$, can be described by the equation
$$\lambda (2x-y+z+1)+\mu(x+y+1)=0,\qquad  \lambda,\mu\in\mathbf R,$$
where $\lambda,\mu$ are defined are to a constant factor, i.e.
$$(2\lambda+\mu)c+(-\lambda+\mu)y+\lambda z+\lambda+\mu=0$$
Write that the point $A$ satisfies this equation and deduce the value of the ratio $\lambda:\mu$.